# Get current user id in dbcontext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I am working on an ASP.NET Core web application. This application works with a SQL Server database and I am using Entity Framework 6.

I want to automatically add, on each entity, a last modification date and user id.

My question is: how can I automatically set the user id to each entity?

I have tried to override `SaveChanges()` in the `DbContext`. It works fine, but I can't access the Microsoft identity classes there...

Thanks

Comment: Are you using **EF 6** for the full/legacy/Windows-only .NET Framework - or **EF Core 6** for the newer .NET Core platform? You have both tags - please be clear and precise in your tagging!

Comment: A simple option is that typically when a user logs into an application you can store a session variable with the typical details about the user such as User Id, display name, and login time to use when rendering page headers for instance and can be verified to ensure a session is still "alive" or has been resurrected after timing out. That can provide a UserId for managing a CreatedBy type SaveChanges override. To use a method like this when running on a load-balanced web server you either need a session state manager (recommended) or sticky sessions.

Comment: I am using EF6 Core sorry. @StevePy how can I read session in dbcontext file ? Thanks

Comment: I have added an example of an implementation I use for web applications that are using Forms Authentication. The common interfaces allows you to build classes for WinForm vs. WCF authentication. I also use a session wrapper for session state for MVC which the Forms Auth. uses to store and fetch the authenticated user. The one step not shown would be on successful login, populating a UserDetails object and using SessionHelper to set the CurrentUser instance. (Should be pretty easy to work out. :)

Answer (score 0):

(Apologies in advance if the method signatures look a bit odd, I'm one of the rare breed that uses explicit interface implementation to help avoid stale code dust-bunnies littering code as I re-factor)

An example on accessing a session state to get the user from within a DbContext using a session token from a Forms Authentication web application:

```
[Serializable]
public class UserDetails
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public interface ISessionHelper
{
    UserDetails CurrentUser { get; set; }

    void Clear();

    bool IsAuthenticated();
}

public class SessionHelper : ISessionHelper
{
    private const string UserDetailsKey = "YourUniqueSessionIdKey";

    private ISessionHelper This => this;

    UserDetails ISessionHelper.CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                var token = (UserDetails)HttpContext.Current.Session[UserDetailsKey];
                return token;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("The current session could not be resolved.");
            }
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[UserDetailsKey] = value;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("The current session state could not be set.");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="ISessionHelper.Clear"/>
    /// </summary>
    void ISessionHelper.Clear()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="ISessionHelper.IsAuthenticated(string)"/>       
    /// </summary>
    bool ISessionHelper.IsAuthenticated()
    {
        try
        {
            var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
            var userDetails = This.CurrentUser;

            return (userDetails != null && userDetails.UserId != 0);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public interface ICurrentUserLocator
{
    bool IsUserLoggedIn { get; }
    int CurrentUserId { get; }
    string CurrentUserDisplayName { get; }
}

public sealed class FormsAuthenticationUserLocator : ICurrentUserLocator
{
    private const string UnauthorizedAccessExceptionMessage = "No user is currently logged in.";

    private readonly ISessionHelper _sessionHelper = null;

    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    private ICurrentUserLocator This => this;

    private UserDetails _userDetails = null;
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    private UserDetails CurrentUser
    {
        get { return _userDetails ?? (_userDetails = SessionHelper.UserDetails); }
    }

    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    bool ICurrentUserLocator.IsUserLoggedIn => CurrentUser != null;

    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    int ICurrentUserLocator.CurrentUserId => CurrentUser?.UserId ?? throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessExceptionMessage);

    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    string ICurrentUserLocator.CurrentUserDisplayName => CurrentUser?.DisplayName ?? throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessExceptionMessage);

   public FormsAuthenticationUserLocator(ISessionHelper sessionHelper)
    {
        _sessionHelper = sessionHelper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("sessioNHelper");
    }
}
```

Assuming you are using dependency injection with a container, register the two classes against their respective interfaces in the container on a per-request lifespan. Then add a dependency on ICurrentUserLocator into your DbContext:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
     private readonly ICurrentUserLocator _currentUserLocator = null;


     public AppDbContext(ICurrentUserLocator currentUserLocator)
     {
         _currentUserLocator = currentUserLocator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("currentUserLocator");
     }
}
```

Now in your overridden SaveChanges you can fetch the current user ID:

```
            var currentUser = Users.Single(x => x.UserId == _currentUserLocator.CurrentUserId);
            var updatedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified)
                .Select(x => x.Entity)
                .Cast<EditableEntityBase>();
            foreach (var entity in updatedEntities)
            {
                entity.LastModifiedBy = currentUser;
                entity.LastModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
            }

            var insertedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added)
                .Select(x => x.Entity)
                .Cast<EditableEntityBase>();
            foreach (var entity in insertedEntities)
            {
                entity.CreatedBy = entity.LastModifiedBy = currentUser;
                entity.CreatedAt = entity.LastModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;
            }
```

If you only expose the FKs rather than user navigation properties then you can just set the ID. If your app has a Log Out feature be sure to call the SessionHelper.Clear() method. In this example I modified the session helper I typically use to just focus on the current user details to keep it simple. It normally tracks a few other details, hence why the Clear() method wipes the entire session. It's a standardized wrapper for handling known session state rather than littering code with `Session["somestring"]` everywhere.